# mongo aggregation: Use string match

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have my documents in the below format

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56119c0fe4b0f3b51d0132b1"), "ua" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0; SM-G900V Build/LRX21T) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/37.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36", "userId" : "55e5d92ce4b0cc9c0a1f1633" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56119c0fe4b0f3b51d0132b4"), "ua" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0; SM-G900V Build/LRX21T) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/37.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36", "userId" : "55f09147e4b0cc9c0a2cfe34" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56119ef6e4b0f3b51d013abe"), "ua" : "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_0_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/12A405 (5726401600)", "userId" : "55f09147e4b0cc9c0a2cfe34" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56119f64e4b0f3b51d013ae7"), "ua" : "Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU iPhone OS 8_0_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/12A405 (5726401600)", "userId" : "55f09147e4b0cc9c0a2cfe35" }
```

The field `ua` has the user agent string which basically contains the user device information. I wanted find out which users are using iOS(if string contains 'iPhone/iPad') vs Android(if string contains 'Android'). Essentially I want the output like below

```
{ "userId" : "56153199e4b0f3b51d043d36" , "iOS": "Yes", "Android" : "No"}
{ "userId" : "55f09147e4b0cc9c0a2cfe34" , "iOS": "Yes", "Android" : "Yes"}
{ "userId" : "56153199e4b0f3b51d043d36" , "iOS": "No", "Android" : "Yes"}
```

How does the aggregate query for this look like?

Comment: Could not find a way with Aggregation framework. Try my MapReduce example and let me know if this works.

Comment: Thank you. This works for me. I do not see your MapReduce answer you posted here anymore !!

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you not to do On-the-go query processing. because It might slow down your processing when you have huge data.

my ideal way of doing this could be, post-process the user-agent or process incoming data while inserting itself.

for example,Let's say you going to insert below document.

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56119c0fe4b0f3b51d0132b1"), "ua" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0; SM-G900V Build/LRX21T) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/37.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36", "userId" : "55e5d92ce4b0cc9c0a1f1633" }
```

you convert above into below one:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56119c0fe4b0f3b51d0132b1"), "ua" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0; SM-G900V Build/LRX21T) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/37.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36", "userId" : "55e5d92ce4b0cc9c0a1f1633" ,"android":true, "ios":false}
```

then, you can query like below to get user who using android, not ios like below:

```
db.collection_name.find({"android":true, "ios":false})
```

which is faster than doing it on-the-go every time.